# Uploading base64 hashed image to Cloudinary

Tags: php, base64, cloudinary

Is there a way to upload an image as a base64 hash to Cloudinary? I cannot find a parameter for PHP uploader library.

```
Cloudinary's upload API call accepts the following options:

file - The resource to upload. Can be one of the following:
A local path (e.g., '/home/my_image.jpg').
An HTTP URL of a resource available on the Internet (e.g., 'http://www.example.com/image.jpg').
A URL of a file in a private S3 bucket white-listed for your account (e.g., 's3://my-bucket/my-path/my-file.jpg')
```

says here: http://cloudinary.com/documentation/php_image_upload

Answer (score 2):

Cloudinary supports uploading files using a base64 encoded data of the image. 
You should make sure that you send your content as a Data-URI as explained here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_URI_scheme.

For example in PHP:

```
\Cloudinary\Uploader::upload("data:image/jpeg;base64...")
```

Comment: Yes, of course. `cloudinary.uploader.upload('data:image/jpg;base64...')`